# Ripple effect in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show ripple effect in my recycler view items. I have added `android:clickable="true"` and `android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"`. 
It works fine. But what I want is to have some delay so that I can show the ripple effect then take to DetailActivity. Right now it happens so fast that the ripple effect is not seen.
I have added delay using **"Handler"**, it works fine. Is this is the right way to do ? (or) is there any other better approach ?

Comment: Suggest you use [Material Ripple Layout](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

Comment: Delay after click is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) that has `setOnRippleCompleteListener`

example :

```
rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
            Log.d("Sample", "Ripple completed");
        }

    });
```